# CloudWatch Alarm : Pending Confirmation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I have created a CW alarm using a CloudFormation Template which looks something like this

```
MyAlarm:
 Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
 DependsOn: CodePipelineSNSTopic
 Properties: 
  ActionsEnabled: TRUE
  AlarmActions: 
    - !Ref CodePipelineSNSTopic
  AlarmDescription: DynamoDB-Alarm
  AlarmName: DynamoDB
  DatapointsToAlarm: 1
  Dimensions: 
    - 
      Name: TableName
      Value: APIGroups
  ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold      
  EvaluationPeriods: 1
  MetricName: ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits
  Namespace: AWS/DynamoDB
  Period: 300
  Statistic: Average
  Threshold: 1
```

The SNS topic has been subscribed to and email has been confirmed.
[image: As seen here]

However in the CloudWatch console it says `Pending Confirmation` What am I doing wrong? Please help me out.

[image: What am I doing wrong]

Comment: Have you confirmed your email subscription? You should get email with a link to  confirm  that you agree to be subscribed.

Comment: As you can see I've already confirmed the email. The screenshot of the same is attached.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @JonatanDragon yes. I wrote to AWS support about this and what happened was that if a subscription is created for a topic and you delete the topic and create another topic with the same name, the alarm action refers to the old subscription made for the old topic for the same name. So you need to give the topic a new name every time if you're deleting it. Surprised they didn't fix this yet. They confirmed it to be a bug and said were working on the fix.

Comment: @RedBottle still they have same bug. thank you for your comment.

Comment: Still relevant. :(

Comment: this is happening to me right now, so horrible!

Comment: Still happening in Nov 2023 :X

Comment: dec 2023 and still eating the pickle on this one