# Why Cloudwatch Alarm is showing warning as Pending Confirmation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, cloudwatch-alarms

I have created a Cloudwatch alarm using a CloudFormation Template and the SNS topic has been subscribed to and email has been confirmed. However in the CloudWatch console it says 'Pending Confirmation'. I am sending an email to a 'DL' and I have added my email into that DL. Also I personaly confirmed the email saying 'AWS Notification - Subscription Confirmation' When I recevied that confirmation email. I am not giving name to the Alarm topic explicitly in cloudformation. So even if I delete it, it should create a new topic name automatically by AWS after creating it again. Can someone help that what 'Pending confirmation' means in this case? And what needs to be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694223/cloudwatch-alarm-pending-confirmation

Comment: Thanks but I already gone through that link. In my case I have not given topic name explicitly in cloudformation so aws cloudformation will generate it by its own even after deleting and creating it again. In that link they have mentioned like you need to give the topic a new name every time if you're deleting it. So My scenario is different than this.

Comment: When you create new stack, do you delete the old stack and create a new one or make some changes. Do you see subscribed in sns topic or also there you see pending confirmation>

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an AWS Support Ticket for the same issue.  Their response:

"This may be the result of a known bug with the SNS service where "orphaned" pending subscriptions cause a false 'Pending Confirmation'."

Also, "The 'Pending Confirmation' that you observe is due the SNS topic being deleted and recreated with the same name."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).